# How to use wildcard for datetime filed

Tags: sql-server

How do I use wildcards for datetme? SubmitDate field is a datetime but the query that I tried returns something totally different. I want records where submitDate begins with 2019-08

This is the code I've tried:

```
select * 
from INVPol
where SubmitDate like '[2019-08]%'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"*How do I use wildcards for datetme"* Quite simply, you don't. Use proper date logic. For what you have the *best* way would be the below

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.INCPol
WHERE SubmitDate >= '20190801'
  AND SubmitDate < '20190901';
```

Using a lower boundary with a greater or equal to, and an upper boundary with a less than will mean that every row with a date in August 2019 will be returned. This is generally seen as a the "best" way as it's the most encompassing. Logic using `BETWEEN` can give incorrect results when using values with a time portion. That's because `2019-08-31T00:00:00.0000001` is **not** `BETWEEN '20190801' and '20190831'` (it's 1/1000000 of a second after the end threshold); this would mean you would effective lose a days worth of values. Also the date `'2019-09-01T00:00:00.0000000'` *is* `BETWEEN '20190801' AND '20190901'`, so you could get (some) unwanted rows.

Trying to use a wildcard on a date would mean you would have to convert the value of the column to a `varchar`, which will cause performance issues. Leave the date as a date and time datatype and query it as one.